# What did Nathan Rosen (from EPR) say about Bell's inequality and its violation?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

Motivated by this year's [Nobel prize in physics](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2022/press-release/), I was wondering whether there are recorded statements by [Nathan Rosen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Rosen) (the R in the [EPR-paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox)) about the Bell inequality and its violation by this years laureates?

Rosen, 1909-1995, was the only one alive of the trio when Bell made the theoretical discoveries (1964), and Clauser's first experiment (1974) and even Aspect's refined experiment in the late 1980s.

Wikipedia and Google search did not reveal anything about this historic debate.

Answer (score 1):

Rosen N., Bell’s theorem and quantum mechanics, American Journal of Physics 62, 109 (1994); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17626

Comment: As in the usual in SE, it is recommended that you summarize the content of the links you provide and showing how it provides a solution to the question.